calculate the accurate postion data from the imu accelarometer in python
can u provide any information about how to calculate position accurately from the accelerometer values from the mpu 6050 sensor in python .I tried by double integrating the the accelerometer values to get the position values but the position values are very bad.
I tried by double integrating the the accelerometer values to get the position values but the position values are very bad.

How noisy are your accelerometer readings? Have you tried smoothing them first?
